# how to parse output of getAttribute (jmx) in jython/python

Tags: python, jython, jmx

I am facing a problem using jython.
I get get the value printed when I access a MBean with a jython/python script, but I would like to parse the result so that I could just extract what is necessary.

Here is the code and the output :

```
def get_attribute(mbean,attribute):
    #<domain>:type=<type>
    obn = javax.management.ObjectName(mbean)
    #<attribute> ie: HeapMemoryUsage
    return remote.getAttribute(obn, attribute)

print get_attribute("java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage")
```

The output in text is :

javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)))),contents={committed=61276160, init=63313088, max=129761280, used=30232944})

If somebody could give me some example or idea that would be great.

Thanks a lot.

For example with Jython, if you want to get the information about one MBean, then it is easy to call :

```
print remote.getMBeanInfo(ObjectName("java.lang:type=Memory"))
```

But again, the output is something like that :

```
javax.management.MBeanInfo[description=Information on the management interface of the MBean, attributes=[javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Verbose, name=Verbose, type=boolean, read/write, isIs, descriptor={openType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Boolean), originalType=boolean}], javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport(name=HeapMemoryUsage,openType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)))),default=null,minValue=null,maxValue=null,legalValues=null,descriptor={openType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)))), originalType=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage}), javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=ObjectPendingFinalizationCount, name=ObjectPendingFinalizationCount, type=int, read-only, descriptor={openType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Integer), originalType=int}], javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport(name=NonHeapMemoryUsage,openType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)))),default=null,minValue=null,maxValue=null,legalValues=null,descriptor={openType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Long)))), originalType=java.lang.management.MemoryUsage}), javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport(name=ObjectName,openType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=javax.management.ObjectName),default=null,minValue=null,maxValue=null,legalValues=null,descriptor={openType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=javax.management.ObjectName), originalType=javax.management.ObjectName})], constructors=[], operations=[javax.management.MBeanOperationInfo[description=gc, name=gc, returnType=void, signature=[], impact=unknown, descriptor={openType=javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType(name=java.lang.Void), originalType=void}]], notifications=[javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo[description=Memory Notification, name=javax.management.Notification, notifTypes=[java.management.memory.threshold.exceeded, java.management.memory.collection.threshold.exceeded], descriptor={}]], descriptor={immutableInfo=true, interfaceClassName=java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean, mxbean=true}]
```

So, if somebody knows a nice way to parse those output into some object, to get a pretty display, please give a comment.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

The idea is to save the result as an object. Then call the method `get("")` on that object, ie. `obj.get("committed")`. 
Actually when calling `"print obj"`, i obtain the same result as above because I believe `python` call the `toString()` method of that object.

I post a sample code hoping it will help somebody.

```
  1 import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
  2 import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
  3 import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
  4 import javax.management.ObjectName as ObjectName;
  5 import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
  6 import sys, cmd, socket, optparse
  7 from urlparse import urljoin
  8 from cmd import Cmd
  9 
 10 def get_connection(host, port):
 11     serviceURL = str()
 12     serviceURL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://"
 13     serviceURL = serviceURL + host + ":" + str(port) + "/jmxrmi"
 14         url =  javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL(serviceURL);
 15         connector = javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
 16         global remote
 17         remote = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
 18 
 19 def get_domain_list():
 20         domainList = []
 21         get_connection('127.0.0.1', 1099)
 22         domainList = remote.getDomains()
 23         return domainList
 24 
 25 def print_domain_list():
 26         domainList = get_domain_list()
 27         for element in domainList:
 28             print element
 29 
 30 def get_domain_objects(domain):
 31         pass
 32 
 33 def get_object_list():
 34         dmiDomains = {}
 35         domainList = get_domain_list()
 36         for element in domainList:
 37         print element
 38         str = element + ":*"
 39         for ele in remote.queryNames(ObjectName(str),None):
 40             print "\t\t" + ele.toString()
 41         return dmiDomains
 42 
 43 def get_mbean_list():
 44         dmiDomains = {}
 45         domainList = get_domain_list()
 46         for element in domainList:
 47         print element
 48         str = element + ":*"
 49         for ele in remote.queryMBeans(ObjectName(str),None):
 50             print "\t\t" + ele.toString()
 51     
 52     obj = remote.getMBeanInfo(ObjectName("java.lang:type=Memory"))
 53     print obj.getClass();
 54     for element in obj.getAttributes():
 55         print element.toString() + "\n"
 56     return dmiDomains
 57 
 58 def get_attribute(mbean,attribute):
 59         #<domain>:type=<type>
 60         obn = javax.management.ObjectName(mbean)
 61     #<attribute> ie: HeapMemoryUsage
 62         return remote.getAttribute(obn, attribute)
 63 
 64 print print_domain_list()
 65 print get_object_list()
 66 print get_mbean_list()
 67 
 68 obj = get_attribute("java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage")
 69 print "="*25
 70 print "Heap Memory usage :"
 71 print "="*25
 72 print "Commited bytes : " + str(obj.get("committed"))
 73 print "Init bytes : " + str(obj.get("init"))
 74 print "Max bytes : " + str(obj.get("max"))
 75 print "Used bytes : " + str(obj.get("used"))
 76 print "="*25
```